# synchronized block and method not working as intended

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized, java.util.concurrent

Status: adding static to the method, variable queue and making synchronized(crawler.class)  solved the problem. thanks all!!

http://pastie.org/8724549#41-42,46,49,100-101,188-189,191

the highlighted method / block is `synchronized`.

That block/method should `be accessed by one method at a particular time.`.

It should be like this =  first thread goes in the method, updates size, all others see that size. updated one. the update should have been only made by the first thread. not others

1. why its even being run .  its being run by all 11 threads.
2. it is runing without waiting for the prior thread to finish. "`queue loaded, new  size ------------`" its creating/ adding elements

```
package crawler;

import crawler.Main;
import static crawler.Main.basicDAO;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


/**
 *
 * @author syncsys
 */
public class Crawler implements Runnable, InterfaceForConstants {
public static final String patternString = "[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})";
public ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Link> queue =  new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Link>();
private volatile String url;





    private void crawl(String url) {


        synchronized (Crawler.class){
            System.out.println("queue size "+queue.size());
            if(queue.size() < (totalSizeOfEmailBucket / 3)){
                updateQueue();
            }
        System.out.println("This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size "+queue.size());
        }
        System.out.println("This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size "+queue.size());





        BufferedReader bf = null;
        try {
            url = queue.poll().getLink();
            URL target = new URL(url);
            bf = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(target.openStream())
                 );
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                html.append(inputLine);
            }
            List emailList = new ArrayList( getEmailList(html.toString()) );
           // List linkList = new ArrayList( getLinkList(html.toString(), url) );
            System.out.println("Just worked on --------- "+ url);
            Main.processedLinksCount++;
            if(emailList.size()>0){
                putEmailsInDB(emailList);
            }

            // putLinksInDB(linkList);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logging.logError(ex.toString());
            basicDAO.deleteLink(url);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logging.logError(ex.toString()); 
            basicDAO.deleteLink(url);
        }finally{
            if(bf !=null){
                try {
                bf.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logging.logError(ex.toString());
                }

            }
            crawl(null);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void  updateQueue() {



            Queue<Link> tempQueue =  new PriorityQueue<Link>();
            tempQueue = getNonProcessedLinkFromDB() ;

            queue.addAll(tempQueue);
            BasicDAO.markLinkAsProcesed(tempQueue);
            System.out.println("queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ "+queue.size());

    }

    private  List getLinkList(String html, String url) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements bodies = doc.select("body");
        List linkList =  new ArrayList();
        for(Element body : bodies ){
            Elements aTags = body.getElementsByTag("a");
            for (Element a: aTags){
               String link =  a.attr("href");
               if ( !(link.startsWith("#")) 
                     && 
                    !(link.contains("()"))
                     && 
                    !(link.endsWith(".jpg")) 
                     && 
                    !(link.endsWith(".jpeg"))  
                     && 
                    !(link.endsWith(".png"))  
                     && 
                    !(link.endsWith(".gif"))     ){

                    if( link.startsWith("/") ){
                        link = url+link;
                    }
                 linkList.add(link);
                 //put link in db
               }    
            }
        }

        return linkList;
    }

    private  List getEmailList(String html) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternString);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
        List emailList = new ArrayList();
        while(m.find()){
            emailList.add(m.group());
            Main.nonUniqueEmailsCount++;
        }

        return emailList;    
    }



    private Queue<Link> getNonProcessedLinkFromDB() {
        return ( basicDAO.getNonProcessedLink() );
    }

    private  void putEmailsInDB(List emailList) {
        basicDAO.insertEmail(emailList);
    }

    private  void putLinksInDB(List linkList) {
       basicDAO.insertLinks(linkList);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(url != null){
            crawl(url);
        }else{
 //          crawl();
        }

    }
    public Crawler(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Crawler(){
        this.url =  null;
    }
}
```

way of starting threads: non optimistic. I know. no executor service or pool used but the following is valid code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {


                    try {



                             Thread thread = new Thread(new Crawler("https://www.google.com.pk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=-q8vUqqNDIny4QTLlYCwAQ#q=pakistan"/*new BasicDAO().getNonProcessedLink()*/)); 
                             System.out.println("resume with saved link true");


                        thread.start();

                        System.out.println("thread stared");
                        threadList.add(thread);
                        System.out.println("thread added to arraylist");

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        new Logging().logError(ex.toString());
                    }

               }
```

debugs:

```
for 11 threads , its says in logs:

queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue size 0
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue size 0
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue size 0
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue size 0
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue size 0
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue size 0
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue size 0
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue size 0
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue size 0
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
queue size 0
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1000
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1000
Just worked on --------- http://ao.com/Advice/Washing-Machines/Top-Tens/Top-Five-Washing-Machines/Advice/Freezers/Top-Tens/Top-Five-Freezers/flavel
queue size 999
Just worked on --------- http://ao.com/Advice/Washing-Machines/Top-Tens/Top-Five-Washing-Machines/l/fridges-width_less_than_50_cm/1-26/29-30//zanussi
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1999
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1999
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1999
queue size 999
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1999
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1999
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1999
Just worked on --------- http://ao.com/Advice/Washing-Machines/Top-Tens/Top-Five-Washing-Machines/Advice/Refrigerators/Top-Tens/Top-Five-Fridges/l/small_appliances-bodum/1-6/55/
queue size 999
queue loaded, new  size ------------------------------------ 1999
This is inside of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1999
This is at the end of sync block.   -----------    queue size 1999
8692 characters / 254 lines
Advertising from Carbon:
Advertisement Braintree: 2.9% and 30¢ per transaction. No minimums, no monthly fees.
```

Comment: Let's also see where you are creating and starting your threads.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you just answered and removed you answer? why?

Comment: Because I'm unsure what the behavior you don't understand is. Can you clarify your expectations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will not behave as expected because of this line:
        synchronized (Crawler.class)
You have taken a lock on 'Class' object of Crawler which would be one per classloader, BUT your synchronized methods are non-static. Replace non-static synchronized methods with static synchronized methods and that should solve the problem.

Comment: nice point about the static/non-static method. what should I do / replace for the synchronized block ?

Comment: nothing much. I see just one synchronized method so just replace public synchronized void  updateQueue()  with public static synchronized void  updateQueue() and probably the compiler will also expect you to make 'queue' as a static variable so you may have to also change  public ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Link> queue to public static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Link> queue.

Comment: I would much sooner change the `synchronized(Crawles.class)` block to synchronize on something else rather than changing the methods to `static` methods.

Comment: static synchronized <ReturnType> methodName(..)

Comment: being with my exact code, what should the `synchronized (Crawler.class)` be changed to? I have tried `synchronized(this)` too

Comment: Honestly this answer doesn't explain anything related to the question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it did explained about the static / non-static to me, and comming towards the synchronizedblock

Comment: synchronized (Crawler.class)  should not be changed to anything if you are changing method signature to static synchronized.

Comment: @MasoodAhmad None of that will change anything to your problem `why its even being run . its being run by all 11 threads.`

Comment: Sotirios, I believe the answer explains the reason why the code was not working which is precisely the questions

Comment: Please clarify then because I don't see it. How does it answer why all 11 threads are calling the code inside the `synchronized(Crawler.class)` block if the `updateQueue` method is meant to change the size so that the `if` block returns `false` on the second+ thread?

Comment: sotirios, please re-read the answer with a calm mind. I am not interested in any ego battles and everyone is entitled about their opinion and so are you. Lets behave maturely. I am not being paid to answer here and I do it to help the needy despite my busy schedule and i am sure so do you. We are on the same side.

Comment: The question is `first thread goes in the method, updates size, all others see that size. updated one. the update should have been only made by the first thread. not others. why its even being run . its being run by all 11 threads.`. How does the fact that they are synchronizing on a `Class` object answer that question?

Comment: To reply to someone you should use `@their-name` so they can get a notification.

Comment: Why does this keep getting upvoted? It doesn't address the issue. The provided solution changes nothing on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this

> first thread goes in the method, updates size, all others see that size.

is your expectation, here's the root cause.

Your `queue` field is an instance field

```
public ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Link> queue =  new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Link>();
```

and you have 11 instances

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Crawler("https://www.google.com.pk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=-q8vUqqNDIny4QTLlYCwAQ#q=pakistan"/*new BasicDAO().getNonProcessedLink()*/));
```

so each `Crawler` has its own queue and therefore each thread enters this block

```
if(queue.size() < (totalSizeOfEmailBucket / 3)){
    updateQueue();
}
```

because each thread is updating a different `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` object.

> it is runing without waiting for the prior thread to finish.

This is not true. All the threads will block at

```
synchronized (Crawler.class){
```

but any code outside of that is fair game.

Comment: should I do synchronized(this) instead? or what do I need to change other than adding static word to queue

Comment: @MasoodAhmad There are many issues with your code. The whole point `synchronized` is to block on a shared object monitor around critical sections of your code. `synchronized(this)` won't change anything because you have 11 different objects, ie. 11 different `this` references. Consider using only one `Crawler` object or making them all share the same `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` object.

Comment: @MasoodAhmad Don't make stuff `static` to share them. Pass them as arguments to constructors.

Comment: adding static to the method, variable queue and making synchronized(crawler.class)  solved the problem. thanks all!!

Comment: @MasoodAhmad Please read [this whole tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html). The problem here is shared vs unshared state. Making the method `static` changes nothing. What you need to do is understand how `synchronized` works and how threads interact.